# Adding an option to browser's context menu (browser's extension)

Tags: web, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to write an extension to my browser, which adds one option to context menu induced on selected word. That's what I want to achieve:

I select a word from text on a website.
I click on it right mouse button.
I see a additional position in context menu
When I click it left mouse key, the selected word will be saved on my disk and one of online translators will open with that word.

I'd prefer to write it on Chrome or Firefox.

In which language should I write it? Where can I found tutorials? Is it hard to do? Generally, how to do it? (I have never written extensions)

Comment: with firefox, you can write an extension to anything you want!https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has an [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) for creation and manipulation of Context Menu's.

I have written a sample extension for Context Menu(

> which adds one option to context menu induced on selected word

) in Chrome.

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Context Menu Demo",
  "description": "This gives demo of context menu features",
  "version": "1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons":{"16":"screen.png","48":"screen.png","128":"screen.png"}
}
```

***sample.js***

```
function reportclick(info,tab){
    // Do all you need here when clicked
    console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
}
var item2=chrome.contextMenus.create({"title":"Search for %s in Context Menu","id":"item2","onclick": reportclick,"contexts":["selection"]  },function (){
        // Do what all you need here when created
        console.log("Context Menu 2 Created");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant what about writing to disk part!

Comment: you can use HTML5 local storage or Chrome storage API (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) or HTML5 file systems API for putting content to sand boxed location and reading them

Comment: @bzxcv7: Which console are you looking at? Background? If so, have you selected text and clicked on context menu and checked background console, it works here; Let me know if it still fails?

Comment: Ok, it works in console "_generated_background_page.html" but still does not work in console induced by CTRL + SHIFT + I combination. Why?

Comment: @bzxcv7 : `CTRL + SHIFT + I` combination is for content induced through `content scripts`, since you do not have `content scripts` here in the code;you can not see any output; FYI you have only background scripts, let me know if you need more information.